# vcrpy for Large Data Dump

Tags: python, api, automated-tests

I'm using vcrpy to mock api calls in a unit test. However, one of the api calls produces a lot of data. This data is basically lots of rows of json data, and I'd like to runs tests on (and store as a vcr cassette fixture) only a few rows of this data.

How can I save only part of the data of a given api call?

Comment: How much data is it? If you have enough disk space, run your test and let it pull the large amount of data. Then manually edit the output fixture and remove excess rows. The next time the test runs, it will re-use the reduced-size fixture.

Comment: yeah that's what I was doing, not ideal. In the end I made a test flag for the api endpoint that only returns a subset of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`before_record_response`](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=before_Record_Response) feature of vcrpy. Construct a function to mutate the response to only a few rows of your large response data, and pass this function to `before_record_response`, which only affects recording cassettes on disk, and leaves your api's intact. From the official documentation:

> You can also do response filtering with the before_record_response configuration option. Its usage is similar
>   to the above before_record_request - you can mutate the response, or return None to avoid recording the
>   request and response altogether. For example to hide sensitive data from the request body: